# How to import font file on public folder in rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, fonts

In rails on public folder, I have a css file call font.css with content

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Public Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(ijwRs572Xtc6ZYQws9YVwnNJfJ7QwOk1Fig.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0102-0103, U+0110-0111, U+0128-0129, U+0168-0169, U+01A0-01A1, U+01AF-01B0, U+0300-0301, U+0303-0304, U+0308-0309, U+0323, U+0329, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;
}
```

File `ijwRs572Xtc6ZYQws9YVwnNJfJ7QwOk1Fig.woff2` is also on folder public too. But I dont see my font apply to my page , how url path in this case
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can import fonts in rails like the following:

1. Create a `fonts` directory in `app/assets/` directory.

```
|-app/
|---assets/
|-----fonts/
```

2. Update the asset pipeline

```
# config/application.rb
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'fonts')
```

3. Your css

```
@font-face {
  ...  
  src: url(/assets/ijwRs572Xtc6ZYQws9YVwnNJfJ7QwOk1Fig.woff2) format('woff2');
  ...  
}
```

One more tip: You could write `src:font-url('ijwRs572Xtc6ZYQws9YVwnNJfJ7QwOk1Fig.woff2') format('woff2')` in `sass` files.

Comment: I don't see it works, note that my rails app is API project, but I need css because it contains generate pdf template

Comment: @BìnhTrương where did you store font files? `public/fonts`?